# How to download a page source in batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

I was wondering how I would download the XML source of any webpage in batch.

Say I was downloading `view-source:https://www.google.com/`, how would i get the text and save it as a TXT file on my computer?

The less calling other languages the better, I need to have it at least be batch or powershell.

EDIT: To clarify, I am not filtering anything out here, I just want the raw XML.

Comment: You mean the HTML? Batch files do not have a native command to do this. Normally you would use WGET or CURL external programs. If you can use PowerShell then use the CURL alias which invokes a web request.

Comment: yes I need the raw html (in my case xml but no difference) but does CURL download it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PowerShell 2.0+

In PowerShell 2.0+, you can run the following code to download a website's HTML/XML to a file:

```powershell
$webclient = new-object system.net.webclient;
$webclient.DownloadString('https://www.google.com/') | Set-Content -Path .\file.txt
```

You can reduce this to one line as:

```powershell
(new-object system.net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.google.com/') | Set-Content -Path .\file.txt
```

which can be run from the command line as:

```powershell
powershell.exe -executionpolicy --command "(new-object system.net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.google.com/') | Set-Content -Path .\file.txt"
```

### PowerShell 3.0+

In PowerShell 3.0+, you can run the following code to download a website's HTML/XML to a file (as suggested by Squashman):

```powershell
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.google.com/
$R.Content | Set-Content -Path .\file.txt
```

You can reduce this to one line as:

```powershell
(Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.google.com/).Content | Set-Content -Path .\file.txt
```

which can be run from the command line as:

```powershell
powershell.exe -executionpolicy --command "(Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.google.com/).Content | Set-Content -Path .\filer.txt"
```

In most cases, you'll also need to add code to handle line endings, which are often only `\n`. Many Windows text editors (like Notepad), will not display those, so it would make sense to replace them with `\r\n`.

Comment: The second one worked for me inside powershell itself, but I can't get it to call from batch using `Powershell.exe -executionpolicy $R = Inv...`, not sure why its not working.

Answer (score 2):

From the command-line you can use [curl](/questions/tagged/curl)...

```
curl.exe -s -o "output.txt" https://www.google.com/
```

```
curl.exe -s https://www.google.com/ > "output.txt"
```

...or [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel)

```
xidel.exe -s https://www.google.com/ --download "output.txt"
```

```
xidel.exe -s https://www.google.com/ -e "$raw" > "output.txt"
```